# Select with condition and check

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my table:

```
project_id | task_id | task_name | task_status |
  ---------+---------+-----------+-------------+
      1           12     foo       complete
      2           13     foo       complete
      3         1210     bar       complete
      4         1211     bar         none
      5         1212     xyz         none
      6         1213     zyz         none
```

I want create query where I can select only `tasks_name` where `task_status` "complete" for both `task_id`. For example one task which name `foo` have two `task_id` such as 12 and 13 and both of them have `task_status` complete. In contrast task with name `bar` have only one `task_id` "completed", so its fall for my condition.
I expect get table like this:

```
   project_id | task_id | task_name | task_status |
     ---------+---------+-----------+-------------+
         1           12     foo       complete
         2           13     foo       complete
```

How I can select, check and return where `task_name` is same for each `task_id` and both of them have `task_status` completed

Comment: is `project_id` always unique or at least different for two different tasks? What if there are more than two task with the same name and `complete` status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to do this using min, max and a subquery.

```
Select *
From Tbl
Where task_name In (Select task_name
                    From Tbl
                    Group by task_name
                    Having Min(task_status)=Max(task_status)                
                           And Max(task_status)='complete')
```

Data output:

```
project_id | task_id | task_name | task_status                         
___________|_________|___________|____________
         1 |      12 | foo       | complete    
         2 |      13 | foo       | complete
```

Answer (score 2):

So that means that, per task_name, the number of completed need to be the same as the total number.

> ```
> select project_id, task_id, task_name, task_status
> from 
> (
>   select *
>   , count(case when task_status = 'complete' then 1 end) 
>      over (partition by task_name) as cnt_complete
>   , count(*) 
>      over (partition by task_name) as cnt
>   from yourtable
> ) q
> where cnt = cnt_complete
> ```

| project_id | task_id | task_name | task_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | foo | complete |
| 2 | 13 | foo | complete |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=be0699a9cd1d4b7cb63772d10db35e46)*

Answer (score 2):

Using window  functions to filter task names that are all complete.

```sql
select project_id, task_id, task_name, task_status from 
(
 select *,
  count(*) filter (where task_status = 'complete') over w = count(*) over w all_complete
  from the_table window w as (partition by task_name)
) t 
where all_complete;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(task_status) OVER (PARTITION BY task_name) min_task_status,
              MAX(task_status) OVER (PARTITION BY task_name) max_task_status
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT project_id, task_id, task_name, task_status
FROM cte
WHERE min_task_status = max_task_status AND
      min_task_status = 'complete';
```

Comment: Oracle al the way :)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Except that my answer won't even run on Oracle.  Check the CTE, the table name has no alias, so `SELECT *` would throw an error.

Comment: My joke is about calling window functions 'analytic'.